How can I create an assessment box using tcolorbox?
Could you help me understand how to create this assessment box?


Have a look at the tcolorbox package

Do you know or have insight into how the box in your image was originally made? Given its complexity, it would be hard to reproduce from just an image alone.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This could be a good starting point :)


Full code
% arara: pdflatex
% 'standalone' class used just to visually isolate the graphic
\documentclass{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{margin={2cm 1cm 1cm 1cm}}

% \documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[
%     a4paper,
%     margin=2cm
% ]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Use Latin Modern font for T1 compatibility

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{instructions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[instructions]{resume, leftmargin=*, label=Q\arabic*., before=\bfseries\color{blue!60}}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[questions]{leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*., before=\normalfont\color{black}}

\newlist{answers}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[answers]{label=\Alph*.}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{4A90E2}
\definecolor{secondary}{HTML}{50E3C2}
\definecolor{accent}{HTML}{9013FE}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf.positioning
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.shapes.geometric
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    outerborder/.style  = {blue!60, line cap=round, line width=1mm},
    dashedborder/.style = {secondary, dash pattern=on 8pt off 4pt on 8pt off 12pt on 2pt off 12pt, line cap=round, line width=.8mm, rounded corners=2mm},
    mybackrectangle/.style  = {minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm, rectangle},
    myrectangle/.style  = {minimum width=4cm, minimum height=.8cm, text centered},
    titleblock/.style   = {text=black, text=white, font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries, anchor=center},
}

\newtcolorbox{assessmentbox}[1][]{
    before skip = 2cm,
    width=.5\textwidth,
    #1,% your optional settings
    enhanced,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colback=white,
    borderline={3mm}{-3mm}{blue!30},
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0mm}{-5mm}{1mm}{black!50!white},
    rounded corners,
    top=40pt, bottom=10pt,% space before and after the code
    overlay={%
        \draw[outerborder]
            (frame.north west) -- 
            (frame.north east) --
            (frame.south east) --
            (frame.south west) -- 
            cycle;

        \draw[dashedborder]
            (frame.north west) -- 
            (frame.north east) --
            (frame.south east) --
            (frame.south west) -- 
            cycle;

        \begin{scope}[shift={(frame.north west)}]
            \node (bg1-rectangle) [mybackrectangle, fill=accent, rotate=-5] at (1.25,-.45) {};
            \node (bg2-rectangle) [mybackrectangle, fill=primary, rotate=5] at (1.25,-.45) {};
            \node (title-rectangle) [myrectangle, fill=secondary, rotate=0] at (1.25,-.45) {};
            \node (title) [titleblock, rotate=0, xshift=0cm] at (title-rectangle.center) {ASSESSMENT};
        \end{scope}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{assessmentbox}
    \begin{instructions}
        \item My instructions:
        \begin{questions}
            \item Question?
            \begin{answers}
                \item AnswerA
                \item AnswerB
                \item AnswerC
            \end{answers}
        \end{questions}
    \end{instructions}
    \begin{instructions}
        \item My instructions:
        \begin{questions}
            \item Question?
            \begin{answers}
                \item AnswerA
                \item AnswerB
                \item AnswerC
            \end{answers}
        \end{questions}
    \end{instructions}
\end{assessmentbox}

\end{document}


Please share your alternative solutions! I'm not a tcolorbox expert and I'm eager to see your ideas!

Thanks a lot Mr.
Emanuele Nardi.. this is very helpfull

I think this solution is pretty dope. I didn't realize tcolorbox was so versatile
